# Install CWM or TWRP on Micromax Bolt A068

Tags: recovery-mode

Device: Micromax Bolt A068

I want to install CWM or TWRP on my phone, but I am not able to do so. I tried using ROM Manager, but it shows a `NOT SUPPORTED DEVICE` message.

Can someone provide to download unofficial CWM or TWRP recovery image that is compatible with my device.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device) for a list of sites which may contain custom ROMs and recoveries for your device.